# Get data from pivot table after save in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have two models `User` and `Role`

`User`:

```
public function roles() {
   $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withPivot('note'); 
}
```

`Role`:

```
public function users() {
   $this->belongsToMany(User::class); 
}
```

When I add another role to the user:

```
$role = $user->roles()->save($some_role, ['note' => 'my note']);
```

I would like to be able to access the pivot id on the role that I just saved like this:

```
$role->pivot; //null
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Laravel doesn't offer this functionality. You have to use something like `$user->roles()->where('roles.id', $some_role->id)[->where('note', 'my note')]->first()->pivot`.

Comment: Thank you, that is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access elements of a pivot table via the related model.

in your example it would be

```
echo $user->roles()->find($some_role->id)->pivot('note');
//-> my note
```

not knowing how your tables are structured I can't help further than inviting you to use `php artisan tinker`

Answer (score 0):

The pivot is not available on `$role` because it is not a `role` object. It should be available on `$some_role`. Try this:

```
$some_role->pivot;
```

Comment: It is not since it the entry in the pivot table is only created upon saving.